# Re-queuing jobs with Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

I am interested in using Resque to distribute work to many different computers. I have one concern though. If I need to kill one of the workers that is working on a job, I would like to be able to have it automatically requeue that job to ensure that it gets run by another worker. I've worked with Django Celery and just do CTRL+C which kills the worker as well as requeues the task. Is there a way for this to happen with Resque in Rails? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure Resque will not requeue automatically? Resque assumes chaos so I wouldn't be surprised if it just works.

Comment: I tried it out. I ran two workers with two different jobs. I did CTRL-C on one of the workers and when I checked Resque-web, it looked as if it had successfully processed the job and the worker I didn't terminate didn't pick up the extra work. =/ If I could just capture that CTRL-C and gracefully have the worker exit and requeue the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out. I can trap the signal term (CTRL-C) and force it to either requeue the job or tell the job to fail and have resque-retry requeue the job at a later time.

For example:

```
def self.perform(args)
  trap("INT") do
     puts "Signal was caught!"
     #either raise an error here if using a tool like resque-retry or requeue the job
   end
  #Do work here
end
```

Sorry for the silly question ;)